# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I'm a not a developer. 
I'm into migration project. I'm trying to migrate an application from VS 2010 to VS 2013, In VS 2010, the application was running fine without any error.

But after Migration, while running the application getting the following run-time error. I'm just got stuck up here.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This method can only be called after the
>   authentication event.

It is small code in Global.asax to checks the rights to application.

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Request.Path.Contains("NoAccess"))
        {
            //Checks rights to application
            var secData = SecurityProvider.GetSecurityData("TEST", Request.LogonUserIdentity, false);

            var access = new SecurityClient(secData).HasAccess("TEST", SecurityAccessLevel.Read);

            if (!access)
            {
                Response.Redirect("NoAccess");
            }
        }
```

The error points to `Request.LogonUserIdentity`

Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Security in the code?

Comment: A quick Google is enough to show you that it is a breaking change (see point 7) http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Comment: Its something related to System.Web.MVC. My doubt is after migrating to VS 2013 am i supposed to do any changes in the code to make these things work. Im really very new to code, im not an expert in coding. So needed help from someone.

Comment: The code doesnt refer to system.security, but it refers to another project which refers to System.Security.Principal.

Comment: The workaround is in the link above - move the code into the PostAuthenticateRequest event as this is the earliest point that the Users Identity is available.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but if you're new to writing and understanding code you shouldn't really be starting out by attempting to migrate a project. Although what do you mean by Migrating from VS2010 to VS2013? Generally you only have problems if you attempt to change the runtime version you're compiling against, not simply opening a project in a new version of Visual Studio. Right click on your project in Visual Studio 2013, navigate to properties. Under properties navigate to Application and check Target Framework. You may need to change it to whatever it was in VS2010.

Comment: Even i havent opened in new vs2013, i changed the target framework, and changed the format version and visual studio version, still was getting the error. thats why posted it here. anyways Kevin has helped me. i got my solution so thanks to Kevin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

"You will receive an ASP.NET 500 – Server Error: This method can only be called after the authentication event. HttpRequest.LogonUserIdentity throws an InvalidOperationException when accessed before PostAuthenticateRequest, because the value of this property is unknown until after the client has been authenticated."

The workaround is to move the code into the PostAuthenticateRequest event (or later)

So add this to your Global.asax

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.Path.Contains("NoAccess"))
    {
        //Checks rights to application
        var secData = SecurityProvider.GetSecurityData("TEST", Request.LogonUserIdentity, false);

        var access = new SecurityClient(secData).HasAccess("TEST", SecurityAccessLevel.Read);

        if (!access)
        {
            Response.Redirect("NoAccess");
        }
    } 
}
```

And then delete all the code from in the Application_BeginRequest event.